# Banach spaces $X$ with $L_2(X)$ isomorphic to $\ell_2(X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I've recently come across this interesting thread

[Banach spaces $X$ with $\ell_2(X)$ not isomorphic to $L_2([0,1],X)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225081/banach-spaces-x-with-ell-2x-not-isomorphic-to-l-20-1-x)

I'm interested in the opposite question. Are conditions known that ensure a Banach space $X$ to satisfy $L_2(X)\simeq \ell_2(X)$? For instance, do superreflexive spaces have this property?